# JetBrains Rider IDE shortcut for printing

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

In JetBrains IntelliJ, one can write just `sout` and the IDE write `System.out.println();`
I know that C# can be used in different types of projects.

- Some projects require printing things in console and thus we need to print things like `Console.WriteLine();`
- Some other projects require printing using `ILogger` like `log.LogInformation();`
- ... etc.

First, I wonder if there is something similar to IntelliJ print shortcut in JetBrains Rider? Then, is there a way to program this shortcut or change this shortcut manually so that it use the suitable print command for the project I work on?

Comment: To verify if a certain feature exists or not, you can contact JetBrains directly https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Comment: This is called Live Templates. You can make your own abbreviations if they do not exist that will expand into the desired text (e.g. `cwl` for `Console.WriteLine();`, `log` for `log.LogInformation()`) etc.) 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_Live_Templates.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Templates_Rider.html

Comment: Use `cw` for `Console.WriteLine()` in Rider. See [the doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Live_Templates_CSHARP.html#Live_cw_CSHARP).